# AngularJS Pagination - How show total pages number inside dir-pagination-controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

I used angularUtils.directives.dirPagination and i want show total number of page next to the pages number .

I use this code :

```
<li><span>page {{pagination.current}} from {{pages.length}}</span></li>
```

inside `dirPaginationControlsTemplateInstaller` function from `dirPagination.js` file .

this is changed function :

```
function dirPaginationControlsTemplateInstaller($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('angularUtils.directives.dirPagination.template',
    '<ul class="pagination" ng-if="1 < pages.length || !autoHide">
    <li><span>page {{pagination.current}} from {{pages.length}}</span></li>
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(1)">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">prev</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by tracker(pageNumber, $index)"
    ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, 
    disabled : pageNumber == \'...\' || ( ! autoHide && pages.length === 1 ) }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a></li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">next</a></li>
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks"  ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.last)">&raquo;</a></li></ul>');
    }
```

But pages.length show max-size='10' when real pages is 19 total page show only 10 .

How can i show real total pages number ?

Comment: will you please add more code?

Comment: it looks like you're showing only your size length .. so how many items the plugin has to take .. plz provide more code

Comment: Where did you stored the pages? Is it an array or an object? What should I understand from the function you included?

Comment: this is orginal sample http://plnkr.co/edit/xmjmIId0c9Glh5QH97xz?p=preview but i edited dirPagination.js in my local for added total page number